# Projection Mapping - transparent faces

Tags: texturing, import, extrude

I'm trying to do as Ian Hubert does in his -now famous- blender speech at BCON19.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whPWKecazgM

At 3.47, he 'import images as a planes' then extrude it.
I try to do the same, but Blender doesn't react the same at all.

When I extrude my wall photo, it just gets semi transparent in a strange way, as if it was hollow.
When I do an edge loop a part of the picture just disappears.

On the right the original pic, on the left the same plane that I extruded and loopcutted vertically in the middle.

[image: extrud loopcut wall]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: understand "Hello!" is gone as the first line of my message :)

Comment: Hi :). Salutations like 'Hello' are removed from posts [automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/). Nothing we can do about it.

Comment: good to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to prevent those transparent faces.

- For Cycles - add some thicknes to the whole wall, before extruding individual parts
- For Eevee  - Set material *Blend Mode* to *Opaque*

*Cycles - add thickness before extruding. Just extrude the whole plane first.*

[image]

*Eevee - set blend mode to Opaque*

[image]

Comment: OK, it gets better when I put this blend mode Opaque indeed, I will try a bit more to see if everything gets fixed.
thanks

Comment: Happy to help :). If it fixes your problem, please mark the answer as accepted **✓**. Thanks :).

Comment: it worked fine thanks again